# Sum of CSV column in Java

Tags: java, excel, csv, sum

I have imported a CSV file into my java application, and I am trying to produce the SUM of one of the columns. However, the result of the SUM that is shown is different to the SUM value I get when i calculate the SUM of the column in Excel Spreadsheet.

I have checked the result of the sum in many different applications and it produces the same result apart from in my java application. There are 3281 lines in my CSV file (this may be a contributing factor).

```
    String csvFile = "1722_schools-number-on-roll-warwickshire-1998-2010.csv";
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    int sum = 0; 
    int  year1 = 0;
    double numbersenrolled = 0;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
            br.readLine();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] studentenroll = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
           year1 = Integer.parseInt(studentenroll[9]);
            //debug the fie and each numbers
            sum = sum + year1;
            numbersenrolled++;



            System.out.println("Number of Students Enrolled [Year 1 = " +    year1 + " , Year 2 = " + studentenroll[10] + "]");

        }

            //sum + median + mean
            System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
            System.out.println("Average: " + (sum/numbersenrolled) );
            System.out.println(numbersenrolled);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: CSV is a lot more than just "comma-separated values".  It has a specific syntax for representing strings, and cannot in general be parsed with `split()`.  Use a real CSV parser such as OpenCSV.

Comment: I am using Netbeans to create my application, would i be able to use OpenCSV?

Comment: OpenCSV works with Java -- which IDE you use is immaterial.

Comment: Get your application to output the numbers it is reading, and compare them to the lines of the CSV.  You could even get it to output the lines into a file that you could paste directly into your spreadsheet, and use an Excel function to compare the two columns.

Comment: @SteveSmith so at the moment I have the 'System out print line' to display all values being imported from the CSV file. Also the number of values being imported are exactly the same as the total number in the excel file, therefore I am just not sure why the sum is different.

Comment: You don't say whether the individual values are the same, only the number values.  If the individual values appear to be the same, try outputting the running total in your program and in Excel, and compare those numbers?  You should be able to see where they deviate.

Comment: @SteveSmith Thank you both, I downloaded OpenCSV and everything is correct now.